# Getting the checked value of a checkbox - Material Design

Tags: cypress

I have a page that uses a basic bootstrap based Admin BSB Material Design [layout](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Core)

I am having difficulty getting a value from the checkboxes in this design.

Example checkbox that is 'checked':

[image]

[image]

I am seeing cypress having no luck finding the checkbox control even if i add a `data-cypress="mycheckbx"` attribute.

So my questions is: how do I obtain the 'checked' property in this scenario?

Styles Used:

```
[type="checkbox"].filled-in:not(:checked)+label:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    left: 6px;
    top: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(37deg);
    transform: rotateZ(37deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 20% 40%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%
}

[type="checkbox"].filled-in:not(:checked)+label:after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #5a5a5a;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0
}

[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked+label:before {
    top: 0;
    left: 1px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 13px;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(37deg);
    transform: rotateZ(37deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%
}

[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked+label:after {
    top: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #26a69a;
    background-color: #26a69a;
    z-index: 0
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the Cypress code you have tried, and explain what you would like it to do. I'm asking this because asserting a box is checked (or not) is not achieved in the same way as actually storing the 'checked' status in a variable (true or false) that you can use latter in your Cypress spec.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems all I needed to do was:

```
cy.get('#pract-haspen').should('have.attr', 'checked')
```

and that Assertion worked!

Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Since none of the solutions above worked for me, I did this :

```js
cy.get('#element').should('be.checked')
```

source : [cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check.html#Options)

The opposite (unchecked) assertion would be (see the official [docs](https://example.cypress.io/commands/actions#uncheck)):

```js
cy.get('#element').should('not.be.checked')
```

Answer (score 6):

This answers ask the question with an assert test in mind.

If you want to get the value and use it somewhere, you can simply:

```
cy.get('#elementQuery').then(elem => {
   var value = elem.val()
   ...do anything you want, like if(value == 'on')...
})
```

Answer (score 5):

If `attr` doesn't work for you, try `prop`:

```
cy.get('#pract-haspen').should('have.prop', 'checked')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great array size too, I'm using this approach to get how many are `:checked` in the screen, `cy.get('.slick-cell input:checked').should('have.length', 13);`